# User permission hierarchy in DB

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to add a permission hierarchy for users e.g. child, parent, admin

My idea is to create a generic user table with usernames and passwords and accessibility which would be from 0 to 2 , 0 - child 1 - parent 2 - admin, but I do not know how to connect the user table to parent/child table since they have different variables.

[Access picture of my database right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQAgy.png)

To be clear parent/child wouldn't have username/password like in this picture anymore with user table.

**Update:**

[DB using only one table for users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POSwb.png)

This table would keep the fields that are only for parents empty if this is a child etc. I would want feedback if the variable 'accessibility' makes sense that would be value from 0 to 2 which would allow me in code to check if it is a parent child or admin

Comment: Your database design is not normalized because you have multiple entities representing the same information.

Comment: What is this database meant to store? What do the entities represent?

Comment: @Dai Basic information about people name, surname etc. I have added a different version of the table that might be more feasible but I'm still waiting on feedback.

Comment: So both "parents" and "children" should be able to login to your system?

Comment: @Dai yes parents, children and admins

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a kind-of table inheritance that prevents two derived entities from sharing the same supertype instance.

Databases like Access and MS SQL Server do not support table-inheritance like how PostgreSQL does, but you can fake it:

```
TABLE Users (
    UserId int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    UserName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PasswordHash binary(32) NOT NULL, -- assuming sha256
    PasswordSalt binary(8) NOT NULL
)

TABLE Parents (
    UserId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    -- insert parent-specific fields here

    FOREIGN KEY UserId REFERENCES Users ( UserId )
)

TABLE Children (
    UserId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    -- insert child-specific fields here

    FOREIGN KEY UserId REFERENCES Users ( UserId )
)
```

This schema means that a `Parent` or `Children` entity cannot exist without a single specific `User` entity also existing. However because Access does not support true table-inheritance it cannot easily constrain `UserId` values such that only 1 `Parent` or `Children` row can have that value (i.e. there can be a `Parent` AND a `Child` that share the same `UserId` value).

Fortunately there's a hack that is mathematically correct (as far as relational-algebra is concerned) but which unfortunately breaks aspects of OOP in that the superclass (`User`) is now aware of it subclasses - but this might be desirable is certain circumstances...

...anyway. the trick is to add an enum value to `User`'s primary key (so it's a composite-key) which identifies a singular subclass, then add a constant (enforced via `CHECK CONSTRAINT`) composite-key component to match in each "derived" table, like so (using pseudo-SQL - the relational-algebra is portable, but concepts like enums and check-constraints don't necessarily port to MS Access very well):

```
ENUM UserType ( HumanParent = 1, HumanChild = 2, Other = 3 )

TABLE Users (
    UserId int IDENTITY(1,1),
    UserType UserType NOT NULL,
    UserName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PasswordHash binary(32) NOT NULL, -- assuming sha256
    PasswordSalt binary(8) NOT NULL

    PRIMARY KEY ( UserId, UserType )
)

TABLE Parents (
    UserId int NOT NULL,
    UserType UserType NOT NULL,
    -- insert parent-specific fields here

    PRIMARY KEY ( UserId, UserType )
    FOREIGN KEY ( UserId, UserType ) REFERENCES Users ( UserId, UserType )
    CHECK CONSTRAINT UserType = 1
)

TABLE Children (
    UserId int NOT NULL,
    UserType UserType NOT NULL,
    -- insert child-specific fields here

    PRIMARY KEY ( UserId, UserType )
    FOREIGN KEY ( UserId, UserType ) REFERENCES Users ( UserId, UserType )
    CHECK CONSTRAINT UserType = 2
)
```

So at the cost of slight inefficiency (i.e. the extra storage needed for the `UserType` columns - and computational expense of evaluating the CHECK constraints) you gain guarantees of the correctness of your data.

Now have fun porting that to Access :)